# How to Extract Chunks from webpack entry compiled output without access to source code

Tags: javascript, webpack

We have a use case where we want to extract the chunks from the entry build file generated using webpack but we do not have access to the source code , we want to build a tree of chunks referred from the main bundle and the subsequent bundles